# Accessing method arguments in Spring.net AOP advice

Tags: c#, aop, spring-aop

I am attempting my first implementation of IAfterReturningAdvice and am wondering how I access the values of the method or if that is even possible? It makes sense that I may have to use around advice to acheive this since I don't have access to the IMethodInvocation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone reads this post later and needs an answer. The answer is that the args[] array contains the arguments passed into the intercepted method.